# vue js table highlight effect similar to Stack Overflow when a new row is added

Tags: javascript, animation, vue.js, html-table

I have a simple table to which the user can add rows. The interface is very similar to this:
https://jsfiddle.net/fgu4q8j0/1/

```
<div id="app">
  <table class="list">
    <tr v-for="(task,index) in tasks">
      <td>{{index+1}}.</td>
      <td>{{task.text}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="text" v-model="newTask" />
  <button type="button" @click="tasks.push({text: newTask})">Add</button>
</div>

new Vue({    
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    newTask: "",
    tasks: [{text: 'task1'}, {text: 'task2'}]
  }
});
```

I want to create highlight effect when a new row is added, which decays slowly - very similar to the orange highlight effect that Stack Overflow has when you click a url that contains a hash (#) to a specific answer/comment.
As I see, Stack Overflow uses jQuery for animation. I look for a CSS only solution, hopefully without doing anything more than `tasks.push(..)`, and maybe integrates into vue transition system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `<tbody name="fade" is="transition-group">` tag around your `tr`'s to make it work with table rows. See [this Github issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/3907#issuecomment-253111682).

```js
new Vue({    
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    newTask: "",
    tasks: [{text: 'task1'}, {text: 'task2'}]
  }
});
```

```css
body {font-size: 20px}

.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  background-color: none;
  transition: all 2s;
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to /* .fade-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */ {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <table class="list">
    <tbody name="fade" is="transition-group">
      <tr v-for="(task,index) in tasks" :key="index">
        <td>{{ index + 1 }}.</td>
        <td>{{ task.text }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <input type="text" v-model="newTask" />
  <button type="button" @click="tasks.push({text: newTask})">Add</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't use list, I do need the table. And I actually prefer this solution, rather than creating a data member just for the transition. I mean, with jQuery after I call .animate(), there is no data or any side effects around after the effect is over

Comment: I've edited the answer to make it work with a table by adding a `<tbody name="fade" is="transition-group">` tag.

Answer (score 2):

You can just do something simple like this by using animation and adding a class for your new items:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    newTask: "",
    tasks: [{
      text: 'task1'
    }, {
      text: 'task2'
    }]
  }
});
```

```css
tr.new {
  animation: blink 2s ease;
}

@keyframes blink {
  0% {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: white;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table class="list">
    <tr v-for="(task,index) in tasks" :class="{new: task.new}">
      <td>{{index+1}}.</td>
      <td>{{task.text}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="text" v-model="newTask" />
  <button type="button" @click="tasks.push({text: newTask, new: true})">Add</button>
</div>
```

If you don't want to track state like this, then you'll have to do things properly and use Vue's `<transition-group>`, and if you check [this](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/6382), it says you need the template option to get around the browser's behavior of stripping tags inside `table`...so you might create a component like this:

```js
Vue.component('tasks-list', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <table class="list">
        <transition-group name="blink">
          <tr v-for="(task,index) in tasks" :key="index">
            <td>{{index+1}}.</td>
            <td>{{task.text}}</td>
          </tr>
        </transition-group>
      </table>
      <input type="text" v-model="newTask" />
      <button type="button" @click="tasks.push({text: newTask, new: true})">Add</button>
    </div>`,
  data() {
    return {
      newTask: "",
      tasks: [{
        text: 'task1'
      }, {
        text: 'task2'
      }]
    }
  }
})
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
});
```

```css
.blink-enter-active,
.blink-leave-active {
  transition: background 2s ease;
  background-color: white;
}

.blink-enter,
.blink-leave-to {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <tasks-list></tasks-list>
</div>
```

Comment: This is good, but I don't like the need for a new data member for added rows. Maybe it is better to create a directive for this? What will be more efficient/performant?